# TSQL - View vs Stored Procedure: Performance considerations when apply predicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Suppose I have a view that's defined as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vData_Values] AS
   SELECT ParentId, TimeStamp, Value From Table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ParentId, TimeStamp, Value FROM Table2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ParentId, TimeStamp, Value FROM Table3
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ParentId, TimeStamp, Value FROM Table4
```

Suppose I write a query against my view as follows:

```
   SELECT ParentId, TimeStamp, Value
   FROM vData_Values
   WHERE ParentId IN (...) and TimeStamp BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '3/31/2013 23:59'
```

Would anyone expect that query against the view to perform differently than a stored procedure with the same inner query as the view, but with the same `WHERE` clause at each step. For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetValues]
(
...
)
AS
BEGIN

   SELECT ParentId, TimeStamp, Value From Table1
   WHERE ParentId IN (...) and TimeStamp BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '3/31/2013 23:59'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ParentId, TimeStamp, Value FROM Table2
   WHERE ParentId IN (...) and TimeStamp BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '3/31/2013 23:59'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ParentId, TimeStamp, Value FROM Table3
   WHERE ParentId IN (...) and TimeStamp BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '3/31/2013 23:59'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ParentId, TimeStamp, Value FROM Table4
   WHERE ParentId IN (...) and TimeStamp BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '3/31/2013 23:59'

END
```

I'm trying to conceptualize if/how these two would be processed/optimized differently. Are there any performance gains by "chunking" up the individual queries and individually applying the predicate to each?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the execution plans. I would expect SQL Server to have no difficulty pushing the predicate in this case. Also you should use an unambiguous dateformat for `datetime` literals and probably not `BETWEEEN` except if the times are definitely not stored with any seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the execution plans

Below have the same execution plans

```
  CREATE VIEW [dbo].[docSVsysInt] AS
  select sID 
  from docSVsys 
  union 
  select sID 
  from docSVint

  select sID 
  from [docSVsysInt] 
  where sID > 100000 and sID <  100010

  select sID 
  from docSVsys 
  where sID > 100000 and sID <  100010
  union 
  select sID 
  from docSVint
  where sID > 100000 and sID <  100010

  select sID 
  from
  (
  select sID 
  from docSVsys 
  union 
  select sID 
  from docSVint
  )  comb
  where sID > 100000 and sID <  100010
```

Answer (score 0):

I myself had exactly this question and found the stored proc version much faster. I believe (and I didn't do much investigating) but I believe in the view it will first do the union of all the records and then filter. The stored proc filters each piece and then unions them so the assumption would be that there are fewer records.

Now something I didn't try was a union all where it includes duplicates (and presumably doesn't check the values.)

So unfortunately, if you are going to process lots and lots of records, between the two samples you show - the stored proc is going to be faster. (I say unfortunately because you have to pre-build the where clause.)

Try looking at the execution plan and see what it says (I'd be curious also.)